# How to pan/scale the contents inside a GUI area?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to have a zoom effect inside an area in a EditorWindow, something like a zoomable scrollview.

The following snippet deals only with the panning effect but it exemplifies the issue I'm having when the contents inside the zoomable area and the clipping rect can't be handled independently of each other through `hSliderValue1` (clipping) and `hSliderValue2` (panning).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

public class ZoomTestWindow : EditorWindow
{
    private static float kEditorWindowTabHeight = 20;
    private static Matrix4x4 _prevGuiMatrix;
    public static float hSliderValue1 = 0;
    public static float hSliderValue2 = 0;

    Rect[] wr = new Rect[]{
        new Rect(0, 0, 100, 100),
        new Rect(50, 50, 100, 100),
        new Rect(100, 100, 100, 100)
    };

    [MenuItem("Window/Zoom Test #%w")]
    private static void Init()
    {
        ZoomTestWindow window = EditorWindow.GetWindow<ZoomTestWindow>("Zoom Test", true, new System.Type[] {
            typeof(UnityEditor.SceneView),
            typeof(EditorWindow).Assembly.GetType("UnityEditor.SceneHierarchyWindow")});

        window.Show();
        EditorWindow.FocusWindowIfItsOpen<ZoomTestWindow>();
    }

    public static Rect BeginZoomArea()
    {
        GUI.EndGroup(); //End the group that Unity began so we're not bound by the EditorWindow

        GUI.BeginGroup(new Rect(hSliderValue1, 0, 200, 200));

        _prevGuiMatrix = GUI.matrix;

        GUI.matrix = Matrix4x4.TRS(new Vector2(hSliderValue2, 0), Quaternion.identity, Vector3.one);;

        return new Rect();
    }

    public static void EndZoomArea()
    {
        GUI.matrix = _prevGuiMatrix;
        GUI.EndGroup();
        GUI.BeginGroup(new Rect(0.0f, kEditorWindowTabHeight, Screen.width, Screen.height - (kEditorWindowTabHeight + 3)));
    }

    public void OnGUI()
    {
        BeginZoomArea();

        BeginWindows();
        wr[0] = GUI.Window(0, wr[0], DrawWindow, "hello");
        wr[1] = GUI.Window(1, wr[1], DrawWindow, "world");
        wr[2] = GUI.Window(2, wr[2], DrawWindow, "!");
        EndWindows();

        EndZoomArea();

        hSliderValue1 = GUI.HorizontalSlider(new Rect(200, 5, 100, 30), hSliderValue1, 0, 100);
        hSliderValue2 = GUI.HorizontalSlider(new Rect(200, 25, 100, 30), hSliderValue2, 0, 100);
    }

    void DrawWindow(int id)
    {
        GUI.Button(new Rect(0, 30, 100, 50), "Wee!");
        GUI.DragWindow();
    }
}
```

[image]

Is there a way to do this, maybe by using a scroll view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Embed the group controlled by `hSliderValue1` inside a new group.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

public class ZoomMoveTestWindow: EditorWindow
{
    private static float kEditorWindowTabHeight = 20;
    private static Matrix4x4 _prevGuiMatrix;
    public static float hSliderValue1 = 0;
    public static float hSliderValue2 = 0;

    Rect[] wr = new Rect[]{
        new Rect(0, 0, 100, 100),
        new Rect(50, 50, 100, 100),
        new Rect(100, 100, 100, 100)
    };

    [MenuItem("Window/Zoom Test #%w")]
    private static void Init()
    {
        ZoomMoveTestWindow window = EditorWindow.GetWindow<ZoomMoveTestWindow>("Zoom Test", true, new System.Type[] {
            typeof(UnityEditor.SceneView),
            typeof(EditorWindow).Assembly.GetType("UnityEditor.SceneHierarchyWindow")});

        window.Show();
        EditorWindow.FocusWindowIfItsOpen<ZoomMoveTestWindow>();
    }

    public static Rect BeginZoomArea(Rect rect)
    {
        GUI.BeginGroup(rect);

        GUI.BeginGroup(new Rect(hSliderValue1, 0, 200, 200));

        _prevGuiMatrix = GUI.matrix;

        GUI.matrix = Matrix4x4.TRS(new Vector2(hSliderValue2, 0), Quaternion.identity, Vector3.one);

        return new Rect();
    }

    public static void EndZoomArea()
    {
        GUI.EndGroup();

        GUI.matrix = _prevGuiMatrix;
        GUI.EndGroup();
        GUI.BeginGroup(new Rect(0.0f, kEditorWindowTabHeight, Screen.width, Screen.height - (kEditorWindowTabHeight + 3)));
    }

    public void OnGUI()
    {
        GUI.EndGroup(); //End the group that Unity began so we're not bound by the EditorWindow

        BeginZoomArea(new Rect(10,10, 200, 200));

        BeginWindows();
        wr[0] = GUI.Window(0, wr[0], DrawWindow, "hello");
        wr[1] = GUI.Window(1, wr[1], DrawWindow, "world");
        wr[2] = GUI.Window(2, wr[2], DrawWindow, "!");
        EndWindows();

        EndZoomArea();

        hSliderValue1 = GUI.HorizontalSlider(new Rect(250, 5, 100, 30), hSliderValue1, 0, 100);
        hSliderValue2 = GUI.HorizontalSlider(new Rect(250, 35, 100, 30), hSliderValue2, 0, 100);
    }

    void DrawWindow(int id)
    {
        GUI.Button(new Rect(0, 30, 100, 50), "Wee!");
        GUI.DragWindow();
    }
}
```

[image: result]

It works but I don't know why. Because the interaction of `GUI.matrix` and `BeginGroup(rect)` is unknown.

PS: [This post](http://martinecker.com/martincodes/unity-editor-window-zooming/) may help you.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn’t work, if you move the window “hello” a bit to the upper-left corner it gets clipped and no matter how you move the sliders it continues being clipped. I think this is because GUI.matrix is applied to the clipping rect too, which makes sense for GUI elements, but it leaves no room for a custom panning or zooming effect. The code in Martin’s post has a workaround which is adding a delta to each GUI element's position instead of to the GUI.matrix